# Upload Large files in Background

Tags: php, http, file-upload, nginx

I'm in the middle of building a system that requires large file uploads - max 2 GB. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this from a UI perspective.

Ideally, I would like the user to be able to select their file and then navigate around and even close the browser window while their file is uploading since an upload may take several hours. While they could pull up a status screen by navigating within my app.

I've looked at AJAX file upload and since my UI is an Angular app it seems this would fulfill the first parts of the requirement, but if they close the browser window it would end.

Finally, I'd strongly prefer to avoid using a plugin like Silverlight or Flash since we don't have that talent in-house. But if that's the only way to achieve these results I would entertain it.

Here's a little info on our stack: Linux running Nginx with a PHP (Laravel) back end and an AngularJS app in front.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a combination of custom Java applet and PLupload for large file (GB+) uploads.

Java applet is using FTP for upload, which is much faster for local intranet users.

PLupload is using multiple runtime plugins; "html5,flash,silverlight,html4", suitable for all users. - http://www.plupload.com

This works for us, and we don't have any Flash or Silverlight developers.

This solution will still be killed if users close their browser, it requires the browser process to work.